# grep extract simple url - without scheme

Tags: regex, grep, sh

I need to extract n url from a file. I've started with:

```
grep -E -o 'ftp://\S*' $filename
```

I know, that this particular url will start with ftp scheme and will end with some white character (space or newline).

I receive something like:

> ftp:/dir/some_file.ext

But I need just a path (/dir/some_file.ext). Without scheme (ftp:// part)

Can I do it with the first regexp? Do I have to use a second one?

I cannot use anything else then grep/egrep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `grep` supports `-P` (PCRE flag) then you can use:

```
grep -oP 'ftp:/\K/\S*' $filename
/dir/some_file.ext
```

If fore some reason you don't have `grep -P` available then pipe with another `grep`:

```
grep -oE 'ftp://\S*' file | grep -oE '/[^/].*'
/dir/some_file.ext
```

Answer (score 1):

This `gnu awk` (due to multiple characters in Record Selector) may also do:

```
awk -v RS="ftp:/" 'NR>1 {print $1}' file
```